# Facebook Messenger Button CSS for Website

Tags: html, css, facebook, messenger

I am trying to embed a Facebook Messenger button on my website for people to get in touch with me. I have the HTML code working but I would like to format it like a Messenger button. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Share your code, so we can see what you have done so far and shed some light into your problem.

Comment: Can you please share your code?

Answer (score 1):

Okay so if you're starting completely froms scratch then here's what I've made for you to toy with, both the HTML and CSS:

```
    <a id="msnnr_btn_anc" href="#mypage">

        <div id="messenger_button">
            <div class="messenger_column btn_label">
                <span>Message me</span>
            </div>
            <div class="messenger_column btn_icon">
                <img src="icon.svg" id="msngr_btn_icon">
            </div>
        </div>

    </a>
```

And some CSS:

```
   <style type="text/css">
        a#msnnr_btn_anc {
            position: relative;
            float: left;
        }

        div#messenger_button {
            position: relative;
            float: left;
            background: #2196F3;
            color: #fff;
            font-family: arial;
            border-radius: 3px;
            overflow: hidden;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        .messenger_column {
            float: left;
            padding: 5px;
        }

        .messenger_column.btn_icon>#msngr_btn_icon {
            float: left;
            width: 28px;
        }

        .messenger_column.btn_label {
            padding: 10px;
            padding-right: 5px;
        }
    </style>

SVG


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
            <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
 viewBox="0 0 76.2 76.2" style="enable-background:new 0 0 76.2 76.2;" xml:space="preserve">
               <style type="text/css">
                   .icon{fill:#FFFFFF;}
                   .icon.blue{fill:#0084FF;}
               </style>

               <g>
                   <path class="icon" d="M38.1,0.2C17.3,0.2,0.4,15.9,0.4,35.3c0,11.1,5.5,20.9,14.1,27.4v13.4L27.3,69c3.4,1,7.1,1.5,10.8,1.5
    c20.8,0,37.7-15.7,37.7-35.1S58.9,0.2,38.1,0.2z M41.9,47.5l-9.6-10.3L13.5,47.5l20.6-22L44,35.8l18.5-10.3L41.9,47.5z" />
               </g>
            </svg>
```

If you're using the fb "send to messenger" API then you might be able to over ride the element styles using their given references.

Comment: By the way, If you happen to not be using the the facebook api, just us it.  unless you really have a specific reason why you want to do it from scratch.

[link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/plugin-reference/message-us)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use fb messenger icon image as a link.
Check the following code snippet :
*[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/jlmmRtJyH3086fXwXChD?p=preview)*

```css
#fb_msg_icon:hover{
  background-color: #eeeeee;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <a href="fb.com/msg/pk1" title="Get in touch with me">
      <img id="fb_msg_icon" width="10%" height="10%" src="http://store-images.s-microsoft.com/image/apps.7488.13510798886918977.69182166-f125-495d-80d2-44fdaab21523.8fcea13e-5d9a-48a9-9937-b26deeced1b5">
    </a>
  </body>

</html>
```